# How to insert CIL code to C#

Tags: c#, cil

Is it possible to insert IL code to C# method?

Answer (score 14):

I just [posted a utility](http://www.glennslayden.com/code/c-sharp/inline-il) which allows entire C# function bodies to be automatically replaced with inline IL, using a custom attribute. Like similar utilities, this works via the ILDASM/ILASM round-trip which can be set up as a post-build step. The tool also adjusts the PDB in order to preserve single-stepping and setting breakpoints on individual IL instructions in the debugger. It's different from some of the other round-trip IL inliners in that it (only) substitutes for entire function bodies, like this:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        [ILFunc(@"
    .locals init ([0] int32 i_arg)
        ldc.i4.3
        ret
    ")]
        int MyFunc(int i_arg)
        {
            return 3;
        }
    };
```

For highly performance-critical methods, I tried using `DynamicMethod` to improve upon compiler-generated IL, but found that the benefit is lost due to the delegate-calling overhead. Inline IL gives the the beneft of hand-tuned IL without that hit, assuming there are no runtime customizations that you would truly need `DynamicMethod` for.

The complete source code is located at http://www.glennslayden.com/code/c-sharp/inline-il

Comment: Didn't find any ILFunc attribute in your lib.

Comment: @Denis I don't think I was providing a lib. It's source code, and there are two files on the web page. The second one (scroll down beyond the additional text) contains the definition for the ILFunc `Attribute` itself.

Comment: Is there a way to write more than just message bodies? So I can use features the cil supports but C# doesnt

Comment: @realbart This method supports any valid CIL code accepted by ILASM.

Answer (score 4):

[DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx) is the lightweight way to accomplish this at runtime.

The Microsoft C# compiler doesn't support injection of IL at compile-time, but a code-weaving tool could do so as a post-compile step.

Answer (score 4):

I'll add my own tool to the list of solutions already provided here: [InlineIL.Fody](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/InlineIL.Fody).

This uses the [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) assembly weaving tool to modify the assembly at build time. Which means all you have to do is install a NuGet package, add a config file to your project and you're done.

You're then provided with a simple and type-safe API to emit IL instructions, which you can mix with C# code. I believe it's easier to write IL in this way than writing text, and it's also more convenient than `ILGenerator` since each opcode gets its own method with relevant overloads only.

Here's an example, with `using static InlineIL.IL.Emit;`:

```
public static void ZeroInit<T>(ref T value)
    where T : struct
{
    Ldarg(nameof(value));
    Ldc_I4_0();
    Sizeof(typeof(T));
    Unaligned(1);
    Initblk();
}
```

This shows how to access the [`initblk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initblk?view=netcore-2.1) instruction which C# doesn't currently expose.

Comment: Woww, I didn't know such great extension! It works great! Seems like inline IL to me :)

Answer (score 3):

If inline IL (in the same spirit of inline assembly supported by C and C++ compilers) is what you're looking for, this can be achieved using post-compilation round-trip compiling.

Mike Stall has once written [a tool for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/tool-to-allow-inline-il-in-c-vb-net), as far as I know it's fairly mature:

Other than that, you could use F# which supports Inline IL.

Comment: Do you know where to find Mike Stall tool? The link is broken. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The tool you need is called **Cecil** and is a part of the Mono project.

You can get more information about it here: http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

Quoted from the website above:

> Cecil is a library written by Jb Evain (http://evain.net/blog/) to generate and inspect programs and libraries in the ECMA CIL format. It has full support for generics, and support some debugging symbol format.
>
> In simple English, with Cecil, you can load existing managed assemblies, browse all the contained types, modify them on the fly and save back to the disk the modified assembly.